# C# equivalent of java Class<E> and E extends Enum<E>

Tags: java, c#, generics, enums

I am trying to translate one Java library into C# code, and since I am new to C# (and never worked with generics until recently) I am strugling a bit...

As for Java generics, I am trying (and more or less understanding) its way of operation. Although I have checked this [Why not extending from Enum<E extends Enum<E>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085296/why-not-extending-from-enume-extends-enume) and this [How to use Class<T> in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462297/how-to-use-classt-in-java), I am not able to really understand whats going on in this piece of Java code, and, as a result, I am not able to think about an equivalent C# code.

```
public abstract class TraciObject<E extends Enum<E>> {
    private final String id;    
    private final EnumMap<E, ReadObjectVarQuery<?>> readQueries;    
    protected TraciObject(String id, Class<E> enumClass) {
        this.id = id;
        readQueries = new EnumMap<E, ReadObjectVarQuery<?>>(enumClass);
    }
    ...
}
```

My approach in C# so far is the following:

```
public abstract class TraciObject<E> where E : Enum<E> { //Non-generic type Enum cannot be used with type arguments
private readonly string id;

private readonly Dictionary<E, ReadObjectVarQuery<E>> readQueries;

protected TraciObject(String id, E enumClass)
{
    this.id = id;
    readQueries = new Dictionary<E, ReadObjectVarQuery<E>>(enumClass); //cannot convert from E  to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer'
}
```

When I have `readQueries = new Dictionary<E, ReadObjectVarQuery<E>>(enumClass);` I was trying to get the corresponding to Java's `EnumMap(Class<K> keyType)`, but checking the documentation about Dictionary https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx I am not sure this is possible

Comment: What is `Enum<E>` and `enumClass`?

Comment: `TraciObject<E> : IEnumerable<E>` is probably what you're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html): `EnumMap(Class<K> keyType)`:

> Creates an empty enum map with the specified key type.

It seems the `Dictionary` constructor you are looking for is the parameterless one.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx):

> `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>()`: Initializes a new instance of the Dictionary class that is empty, has the default initial capacity, and uses the default equality comparer for the key type.