# Map<Enum, Integer> map2 = new EnumMap<what-to-write-to-make-compile???>(map1);

Tags: java, generics, enums

class Enum is defined in API as:

```
public abstract class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>
```

I have

```
enum Cards { Trefs(2.3), Clubs(1.0);
    public double d;

    private Cards(double val) {
        this.d = val;
    }       
}
```

Question 1:

```
Enum e = Cards.Clubs; //compiles, but with warning: "References to generic type Enum<E> should be parameterized"

Enum<???what-shall-I-write-here??> e1 = Cards.Clubs; //Question 1
```

Question 2:

this compiles:

```
        Map<Enum, Integer> map0 = new HashMap<Enum, Integer>();
        Map<Enum, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<Enum, Integer>();
        map1.put(Cards.Clubs, new Integer(54));

        Map<Enum, Integer> map2 = new EnumMap<>(map1);
```

But can I add anything in angle brackets of RHS (new EnumMap), like I did for map1 above?

```
Map<Enum, Integer> map2 = new EnumMap<???what-can-I-write-here??>(map1);
```

P.S. I researched SO, but found nothing **DIRECTLY** **answering** above question.
My research:

1. [angelikalanger FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ106)
2. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451839/angelika-langer-enume-extends-enume-decoding)
3. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085296/why-not-extending-from-enume-extends-enume)
4. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34943604/java-why-is-enume-not-allowed-as-annotation-member)
5. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061759/why-in-java-enum-is-declared-as-enume-extends-enume)

Comment: Try using an IDE, it will fill almost everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: please use this instead:

```
Cards e = Cards.Clubs;
```

Second: Use the [diamond operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html). If you absolutely want, it is `new EnumMap<Cards, Integer>()` but why do you want to write it out?
And please never use `new Integer(54)`. If for whatever reason you do not like [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), use `Integer.valueOf(54)` instead. [It doesn't waste objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974561/new-integer-vs-valueof).

So, I recommend this code:

```
Map<Cards, Integer> map0 = new HashMap<>();
Map<Cards, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put(Cards.Clubs, 54);

Map<Cards, Integer> map2 = new EnumMap<>(map1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is:

```
Enum<Cards> e = Cards.Clubs;

Map<Enum<Cards>, Integer> map0 = new HashMap<>();
Map<Enum<Cards>, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put(Cards.Clubs, 54);
```

But I don't know why the `Map<Enum<Cards>, Integer> map2 = new EnumMap<>(map1);` fails

Edit:

So I think what you want is something like this:

```
Cards e = Cards.Clubs;

Map<Cards, Integer> map0 = new HashMap<>();
Map<Cards, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put(Cards.Clubs, 54);

EnumMap<Cards, Integer> map2 = new EnumMap<>(map1);
```

You don't need to wrap you Enum into an Enum

Comment: Surprisingly, `Enum<Cards> e = Cards.Clubs;` gives a warning "Enum is a raw type. References to generic type Enum<E> should be parameterized". Is there a way to write this without warning?